# How to round numbers with N digits after the zero?

Tags: javascript

lets say I have a number in the following form: 0.00N1N2N3...(for example 0.007).

I want to round the number 0.00N1N2N3...Nn, into the follwoing number:
0.0M1M2M3..Mn.

For example:0.007 need to be round to 0.01.

Now the number can be also in the following form 0.N1...Nn or N1.N2...Nn so the solution need to be generic for all cases.
I have write the following function(Not sure if this is the right answer):

```
function roundup(number, precision) {
  return Math.ceil(number * precision) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable is float you can use `toFixed()` like

```
var formatted = parseFloat("345.65894").toFixed(2);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

On most browsers you can use the `toFixed()` function.

`number.toFixed(precision)`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: thanks for the quick reply